Deploy CRM solution using Package Deployer as update instead of upgrade
We are using the Package deployer for deploying the solution. We want to update the solution instead of the stage for upgrade and upgrade. Is there any way do this?
We have created a solution as we have multiple solution to deploy so we have used package deployer. i tried to look but there is no specific documentation from Microsoft . Is there any way to do that

Unfortunately there is no option to choose how solution import is done.
A workaround could be to skip solution import in the OverrideSolutionImportDecision method and do the import by submitting an ImportSolutionAsyncRequest.
For example code see Solution staging, with asynchronous import and export | MS Learn.

will this be upgrade or update?
as we have option to upgrade without holding soultion

With property ImportSolutionAsyncRequest.HoldingSolution (bool) you can choose whether to update or upgrade.
